# Asynchronous keyboard Assembly MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I need to read asynchronously a character from keyboard in Mars
simulation. For example, I want to print -1 when my program has no input
and 10 when can read from the keyboard. I tried using:

```
.text
loop:
     li $v0, 51
     bne $a1, 0, Imprime2
     j Imprime
```

Imprime:
     li $a0, -1
     li $v0, 1
     syscall
     j loop

Imprime2:
     li $a0, 10
     li $v0, 1
     syscall

`li $v0, 10
 syscall`

But, the output is:
10

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Looking at the MARS system calls seems to imply that this is not possible. I can't tell for sure though, hence a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Try using the memory mapped I/O mode and poll for data. See e.g. http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61cl/fa08/labs/lab25.html

Comment: It's working!! Thank you :D